# GET top 10 using sql in access joining tables

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

These are my tables:

table BUSINESS

```
 BUSINESSUSERNAME|BUSINESSPASSWORD|BUSINESSNAME|
 Res1            |123             |Cafe        |
 Res2            |456             |Foodtruck   |
```

table USER

```
 USERNAME|USERPASSWORD|NAME|
 user1   |123         |mr.1|
 user2   |234         |mr.2|
```

table FOOD

```
FOODID|FOODNAME|FOODPRICE|BUSINESSUSERNAME|
1     |CAKE    | 5       |Res1            |
2     |SHAKE   | 2       |Res2            |
3     |COLA    | 3       |Res1            |
```

table FOOD_RATING

```
FOODREVIEWID|FOODID|FOODRATING|BUSINESSUSERNAME|USERNAME|
1           |2     |3         |Res2            |user1   |
2           |2     |5         |Res2            |user2   |
3           |1     |4         |Res1            |user1   |
4           |3     |1         |Res1            |user1   |
```

I would like to get the top 10 foods based on average rating:

```
RANK|FOODNAME|FODPRICE|AVGRATING|BUSINESSUSERNAME
 1   |CAKE     |5       |4        |Res1
 2   |SHAKE    |3       |4        |Res2
 3   |COLA     |3       |1        |Res1
 .
 .
 .
10
```

Comment: Why do you say join _two_ tables?  Which two tables do you suggest joining?

Comment: Better title now, but aside from that did you at least have an idea of where to start?  Sometimes in Access you can get a good start in the query design view and then switch to sql view.

Comment: `SELECT FOOD.FOODNAME, FOOD.FOODPRICE, IIF (Round(Avg(FOODRATING),1)is null,0,Round(Avg(FOODRATING),1)) AS FOODAVGRATING
FROM FOOD LEFT JOIN FOOD_REVIEW ON FOOD.FOODID = FOOD_REVIEW.FOODID
WHERE (((FOOD.BUSINESSUSERNAME)="someusername"))
GROUP BY FOOD.FOODNAME, FOOD.FOODPRICE;`

Comment: i have that code but i cant see to be able to use the desc function

Comment: i am able to get the average ratings but i cant get them to follow a top 10 order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Added `SELECT TOP 10`

The `ORDER BY` comes after `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT TOP 10 FOOD.FOODNAME, FOOD.FOODPRICE
 , IIF(Round(Avg(FOODRATING), 1) IS NULL, 0, Round(Avg(FOODRATING), 1)) AS FOODAVGRATING
FROM FOOD
LEFT JOIN FOOD_REVIEW ON FOOD.FOODID = FOOD_REVIEW.FOODID
WHERE (((FOOD.BUSINESSUSERNAME) = "someusername"))
GROUP BY FOOD.FOODNAME, FOOD.FOODPRICE
ORDER BY IIF(Round(Avg(FOODRATING), 1) IS NULL, 0, Round(Avg(FOODRATING), 1)) DESC;
```

Comment: one question how do i stop it to 10?